# Unable to change primary display when using dual monitors on Windows 7 in VMWare

Tags: windows-7, development-environment

I am running Windows 7 RC Build 7100 in VMWare 6.5. The host OS is Vista x64 Home Premium running on a Dell Studio 1535 laptop. I have a Dell monitor attached as a secondary monitor, and I am attempting to share the desktop across both monitors.

While I can do that, Windows 7 insists on using the external monitor as the main display, and if I attempt to change the main display to the laptop monitor I am greeted with 'Unable to save display settings.' when I attempt to save. This dialog is shown twice. Has anyone else experienced this or know of a workaround?

Comment: The Windows 7 configuration I am attempting to get working is to be used as my primary development environment, so it is very much related to my programming :-) 

And considering that this type of configuration would not be uncommon in the programming community, I don't see what good it does to consider it as off-topic here. Isn't the whole point of Stack Overflow to allow our shared knowledge to be pooled together and reused in need? Does this same off-topic mandate also apply to other hardware and OS config issues that developers may face when developing and deploying applications?

Comment: from the SO faq "If your question is devoid of source code and pertains to networking, servers, or maintaining desktop PCs other than your own – it should probably be asked on our sister site for system administrators and IT professionals, Server Fault."  

It does say "PC other than your own".  Our main programming PC is withing the scope of SO.

Comment: Well it certainly seems that this question fits within the scope of reasonable use then. I have clarified my intent by adding the development-environment tag. Besides, Server Fault is in private beta, so redirecting the general public to there ATM seems a little.. umm... less than helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Quite late, but perhaps [**VirtualBox**](http://virtualbox.org) would work for you.

Comment: I have the same issue in VirtualBox.  If I try to change my guest OS'es primary display, the guest OS shows "Unable to save display settings." -- twice.